# Given that $f$ and $\ddot{f}$ are bounded, $\dot{f}(x)<0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dot{f}=0$ , Can we conclude that $\ddot{f} \geq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given that $f(x)$ is lower bounded, $\dot{f}(x)<0$ , $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dot{f}=0$ and $\ddot{f}$ is bounded, Can we conclude that $\ddot{f} \geq 0$ , or more specifically $\ddot{f}(x)>0$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ddot{f}=0$ ?

If the given was $\dot{f}$ is bounded, instead of $\ddot{f}$ being bounded , Can the same be said ?

Comment: consider $e^{-x^2}$, $x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just consider $f(x) = -\arctan(x)+ 100$.

Then:

- $f$ is lower bounded;
- $\dot f(x) = - \dfrac{1}{x^2+1}< 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$;
- $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} \dot f(x) =0$;
- $\ddot  f(x) = \dfrac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$ is bounded, but it changes its sign.

**EDIT:**

In this case $\dot f(x)$ is bounded too.

Answer (score 3):

No, we cannot conclude that $f$ is convex. Just draw a graph of a decreasing function which changes from being concave to convex.